# HTML Run Javascript when hovering over a block element?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, triggers, hover

I'm currently trying to make my Tumblr page as nice as possible and set it apart from others. There is a sidebar with menu items that highlight and move to the left slightly when the user hovers over them. However, I would like to also have a sound play when the :hover is triggered.

This is the sidebar Menu code.

```
#sidebar{
margin-left:85px;
margin-top:50px;
{block:IfNotStaticSidebar}position:absolute;{block:IfNotStaticSidebar}
{block:IfStaticSidebar}position:fixed;{/block:IfStaticSidebar}
background-color:{color:Sidebar};
width:200px;
padding:10px;
text-align:justify;
-moz-border-radius: 0px 50px 0px 0px;
-webkit-border-radius: 0px 50px 0px 0px;
-o-border-radius: 0px 50px 0px 0px;
border-radius: 0px 50px 0px 0px;
}

#description{
width:90%;
margin:10px;
}

a.block {
display:inline;
text-align: left;
font-size:10pt;
padding:3px;  
margin:5px;  
position:relative;
background-color:{color:color4};
display: inline-block;
font-family : arial;
color: {color:Menu Links Font};
font-weight: bold;
width: 100px;
transform: rotate(0deg); 
-moz-transform: rotate(0deg); 
-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); 
-o-transform: rotate(0deg);
-webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
-moz-transition: all .5s ease;
-o-transition: all .5s ease;
}

a.block:hover {
color: {color:Menu Links Font Hover};
background-color:{color:color5};
padding-left:20px;
-webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
-moz-transition: all .5s ease;
-o-transition: all .5s ease;
text-shadow:0px 0px 5px {color:Shadow};
}
```

This is the sound code I'm trying to adapt.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function playSoun
d(soundfile) {
document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML=
"<embed src=\""+soundfile+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\" />";
}
</script>
<span id="dummy"></span>
<p onmouseover="playSound('http://www.freesound.org/data/previews/141/141259_2555977-lq.mp3');"> Hover over this text </p>
```

I would greatly appreciate any help with this!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this article](http://css-tricks.com/play-sound-on-hover/).

It explains it pretty perfectly! :)

Well, here is a trick using jQuery:

```
$("p").mouseenter(function(){
    $("<audio></audio>").attr({ 
        'src':'audio_src', 
        'volume':0.4,
        'autoplay':'autoplay'
    }).appendTo("body");
});
```

See the demo [here](http://css-tricks.com/examples/SoundOnHover/).

Answer (score 0):

With `jquery` you can do as follows

```
<p id='psound'>&nbsp;</p>
```

if your element has `id` of `psound`.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $('#psound').hover(function (e) {
       alert('on mouse over');
  }, function (e) {
       alert('on mouse out');
  }); 
</script>
```

both mouse in and mouse out handlers.